# Definition of homotopy fiber

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, model-categories

In [definition 2.2 of nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/fiber+sequence) we define the **homotopy fiber**

> Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism in a model category $C$, its homotopy fiber
> $$hofib(f) \rightarrow X $$
> is given by the morphism in $Ho(C)$  represented by the fiber of any fibrant resolution.

This is confusing to me, given a fibrant resolution
$$ f:X \xrightarrow{\in W} \hat{X} \xrightarrow{f' \in Fib} Y$$
Then we have $fib(f')$ being the fiber of $f'$ i.e. pullback along $* \rightarrow Y$ of $f'$. How does one obtain the morphism
$$fib(f') \rightarrow X $$
in the homotopy category? We only have a map $fib(f') \rightarrow \hat{X}$. Do we post compose by the inverse of $X \xrightarrow{\in W} \hat{X}$?

Comment: If I understand correctly, then $X \rightarrow \hat{X}$ is a weak/homotopy equivalence. This is an isomorphism in the homotopy category (?). Since the objects $X$ and $\hat{X}$ are isomorphic in $Ho(\mathcal{C})$, then yes, post composing by the inverse of $X \rightarrow \hat{X}$ seems right.